# Setting the Value of a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, set, dependency-properties

This seams so simple, yet I never heard of dependency properties at all.
So, I was coding until I tried to set the value of a rich text box.

There's nothing fancy of it, simply the rich text box.

When I try to set the value, I need a dependencyproperty. I heard that this is a .NET-thing but I never needed to use it.

So, could someone tell me, how to do this?

Would this be the solution?:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty myDP = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "richtextbox", typeof(Boolean));
```

to finally to something like this: `rtb.setValue(myDP, "Text");`
And since I have a lot of rich textboxes, do I need to make a dp for every field?

Don't get me wrong, but this is where Google isn't good enough.

Comment: You mean the `Text` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox_properties.aspx) of a `RichTextBox` ?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx), `RichTextBox` doesn't have a `Text` property. It has, however, a [`Document` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx).

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: That's the only GUI-related context that I know which uses something called dependency properties.

Comment: Yes sir, this is happening on the Windows Phone SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `Text` property. `rtb.Text = "Blah blah blah";`

For WPF, you can use the `Document` property with a [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) object. See [guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37368/WPF-Flow-Document-For-Beginners). And example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx):

```
FlowDocument myFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();

// Add paragraphs to the FlowDocument.
myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 1")));
myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 2")));
myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 3")));
RichTextBox myRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();

// Add initial content to the RichTextBox.
myRichTextBox.Document = myFlowDoc;
```

If you ever need to set the property of any control in .net search for the control properties or just press <kbd>F1</kbd> when your caret is inside the control in VisualStudio to see [usage and examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox_properties.aspx%29%20of%20a%20%60RichTextBox%60%20?).

Comment: But I don't plan to use the myRichTextBox so immersive. It would be more like myRichTextBox.Document = "Text"; Is this valid?

Comment: No, it should be a Flow Document, the guide I provided will tell you how to use the `RichTextBox`, If you want something simple I'd suggest you go with a WPF TextBox, which also provides multiline as well as styling...

Answer (score 1):

The contents of a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) can be accessed via its [`Document` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx).

Somehow, something must have given you a totally wrong idea about dependency properties; WPF controls such as `RichTextBox` *have* dependency properties that you can use. There is no need for you to create any if you just want to assign a value.

Also, you almost never have to call the `SetValue` method for any dependency properties; WPF controls and other dependency objects usually offer property wrappers for each dependency property that let you use the properties just as you're used to, so a call to `rtb.Document. ...` should be fine.

**Update:** Thinking about this again, I think the following explanation will also be helpful for you:

You have found the [`SetValue` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx), which requires a `DependencyProperty` for one of its arguments. In general, for any dependency property of any object there is a public static read-only field that exposes the respective `DependencyProperty` instance. For example, the `TextBox` class provides the [`TextProperty` field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textproperty.aspx) for its [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx).

Comment: You mean rtb.Document = "Text here"; ?

Comment: @Clue: No, a `RichTextBox` is not meant for editing simple texts. It needs to be a `FlowDocument`.